# Add a custom button in tool bar tab of Syncfusion report in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I am engaged in some situation , can you help me to add my own custom button inside the tab bar of report ?  You can see the below image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can able to add the customized toolbar icon in ReportViewer control, also collection of font icons are available in ej icon packages and you can use from font icon packages. I have prepared a sample based on this and it can downloaded from,
Sample: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ReportSample807880169.zip

Please refer the below screenshot customized toolbar with font icons.

Also, please refer the below UG Documentation link for more details on this,
https://help.syncfusion.com/js/icon/ej-icons

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._